# Jackson @JsonIgnore on Java child objects - Multiple Use

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
public class Customer{

@Id
private String customerId;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Image profileImage;...
```

Taking above example, lets stay `Customer`class is an instance variable for the two classes -

```
RandomClassA{
..
private Customer customer;
..
}

RandonClassB{
..
private Customer customer;
..
}
```

The issue is I want to **ignore** customer's `Image` and its variables when accessing `RandomClassA`, but I want it to display for `RandonClassB`

Is there any easy way to do it - with some operation on `RandomClassA` and `RandomClassB` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**Found the solution**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"property1","property2"})
```